# The materialized view is already optimal and cannot be tuned any further

Tags: oracle, performance, materialized-view, query-performance

I have tried `DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW` to verify some materialized views created locally. One of the result returns an error:

```
Error report:
ORA-13600: error encountered in Advisor
QSM-03116: The materialized view is already optimal and cannot be tuned any further
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.PRVT_ACCESS_ADVISOR", line 205
ORA-06512: at "SYS.PRVT_TUNE_MVIEW", line 951
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ADVISOR", line 739
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Does this mean the materialized view script is in the best shape, or `DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW` is not capable to find a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a materialized view is already fast refreshable, the `DBMS_ADVISOR.TUNE_MVIEW` procedure will return a message saying "the materialized view is already optimal and cannot be further tuned"

So there is nothing to do.